# parsing particular sections of a file in perl

Tags: perl

I am new in perl and exploring it

I have a .xml file and I am looking to get few sections of it.
Each section starts and ends with `<field>`. and I want to get content in between them

```xml
 <field>
    <address>20</address>
    <startat>0</startat>
    <size>8</size>
 <field>

 <field>
    <address>21</address>
    <startat>0</startat>
    <size>8</size>
<field>
```

and output I am looking as below

```xml
    <address>20</address>
    <startat>0</startat>
    <size>8</size>

    <address>21</address>
    <startat>0</startat>
    <size>8</size>
```

How would I go about extracting that part of the file?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to just remove lines that contain `<field>`? Note that what you show isn't valid XML because there's no closing `</field>`.

Comment: Yes, I just want to remove lines that contain <field>

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Your source XML isn't actually XML. Is this a transcription error, or have you been given broken XML to work with (which is a different problem)?

Answer (score 2):

You may go about this problem by going through the text, but it is always safer to use an XML parser. There are a number of excellent Perl XML libraries available in CPAN. One that I like is `XML::LibXML` (see [here](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0132/LibXML.pod)) which is an interface to `libxml2`. It provides lots of possibilities. Using the functionality of `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` we could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new( recover => 1 );
my $xp = $parser->parse_string(<<'EndXML');
  <document>
    <field>
      <address>20</address>
      <startat>0</startat>
      <size>8</size>
    </field>

    <field>
      <address>21</address>
      <startat>0</startat>
      <size>8</size>
    </field>
  </document>
EndXML

if( $@ ) {
  die "Cannot parse XML\n";
}

foreach my $c ( $xp->findnodes('//field') ) {
  print $c->findnodes('.'), "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
<field>
      <address>20</address>
      <startat>0</startat>
      <size>8</size>
    </field>
<field>
      <address>21</address>
      <startat>0</startat>
      <size>8</size>
    </field>
```

A few comments:

1. The option `recover => 1` may be useful to parse broken XML files. It will not fix all problems, but may be able to fix some of them. Leave empty if you want no fixing. Use `recover => 2` to make the fixing silent.
2. This code uses `findnodes` which takes an [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) expression. In this case `//field` will find any `<field>` tags. Then `findnodes('.')` will get the whole content of the "field".